# Receiving "KeyError" after decoding json result from url

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, decode, urlopen

I am new to Python. I am trying to parse the json result from a url. Originally, I was using the following:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
json_obj = json.load(response)
```

This gave an error along the lines of "JSON object should be 'str' not 'bytes'" so, after searching on stackoverflow, I decoded the response as follows:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
charset = f.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
data = f.read()
decoded = json.loads(data.decode(charset))
```

If I print "decoded" it is as follows:

```
{'Links': {'SummaryData': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE/summary', 'Value': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE/value', 'InterpolatedData': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE/interpolated', 'Self': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/points/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE', 'PlotData': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE/plot', 'DataServer': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/dataservers/s0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAU0hJTExNQU42NDIw', 'RecordedData': 'https://localhost/piwebapi/streams/P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE/recorded'}, 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'SINUSOID', 'WebId': 'P0_7qHaW4UHU-RlCaz8tpasAAQAAAAU0hJTExNQU42NDIwXFNJTlVTT0lE'}
```

Now, whenever I try to pull out a particular value, I get a "KeyError". For example:

```
print(decoded[0])
```

returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 1
06, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 8
2, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\shillman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PythonApplicatio
n1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(decoded[0])
KeyError: 0
```

What format is "decoded" in? Is there a way I can do this where it is actually a dictionary? Is there a way to convert it to a dictionary? Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What format is "decoded" in? Is there a way I can do this where it is actually a dictionary? Is there a way to convert it to a dictionary?

According to what you printed out, `decoded` *is* a dictionary, and that's exactly the problem.

The keys of this dictionary are `'Links'`, `'Name'`, `'Id'`, and `'WebId'`. But `decoded[0]` is looking for a value with the key `0`. There is no such key, so you get an error.

It sounds like what you really wanted was a way to get the first value, by treating the dictionary as if it were a list or other sequence. You *can* treat the keys, or values, or items of a dictionary as a sequence, but not directly, because:

- The order of these things is completely arbitrary.
- There's no reason a dictionary can't have `0` or `1` as a key instead of `'Links'` or `'Name'`.
- Therefore, Python won't let you do it just by using the normal `[]` operator.

If you want to get the first value in the dictionary—while remembering that the order is arbitrary, and "first" may not mean what you want—you can do it like this:

```
list(decoded.values())[0]
```

… or, less wastefully, treat it as an iterable instead of trying to make it into a sequence:

```
next(iter(decoded.values())
```

If you're still using Python 2.x, `values()` actually returns a list, so both of these are wasteful and unnecessary; you'd want to use `next(decoded.itervalues())` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use one of the actual keys, say:

print(decoded['WebID']

I still get "KeyError 'WebID'"

Is that not the way to reference that key?

Comment: Ah, it's case sensitive. I didn't know that. Works now. Thank you!

Comment: @JOEMan90: It's not all that hard to write a case-insensitive dict subclass, and hook the `json` module to return those instead of normal dict values, if you really want to. But JSON itself is inherently case-sensitive, so this could get pretty confusing depending on your input data, and probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` decode the json into python objects. [1]

Your `decoded` is already a python dictionary, but it does not have the key `0`.

You can access the links with `decoded['Links']`

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads

Comment: If I write

print(decoded['WebID'])

I still get

KeyError: 'WebID'.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Ah, case sensitive. I got it. Thank you!